# Is there a way to prevent Copilot to make suggestions about paths

Tags: github, github-copilot

Copilot is suggesting relative paths that are not correct and makes a suggestion each time I write a "/" in my path string
[image]

which prevents me from seeing these path suggestions from my IDE[image]

Is there a way to only disable Copilot for import paths ?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Thanks might be a deal breaker! I find it overriding tools that work all the time, is somewhat cumbersome haha

Comment: Yes it is hahaha. I usually keep Copilot disabled. I only use it when I am stuck or when I need to do create generic code.

Comment: Still waiting on a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ctrl+I to trigger the suggestion feature in VS Code. If it doesn't work, you can go to the shortcut settings of VS Code and find the shortcut key for triggering suggestions